# use shapassword encoding with salt in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to learn Spring boot security currently. I want to add SHA-1 password encoding with salt (salt=username) encoding. What Configurations are needed for this?

Comment: Can you please provide what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder(){

    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
            return new ShaPasswordEncoder().encodePassword(rawPassword.toString(), "salt-example-string");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
            return encodedPassword.equals(rawPassword.toString());
        }
    };
}
```